# How expose the properties of a component created in an ActiveX form?

Tags: delphi, activex

Can you publish the properties of a control that is inside an ActiveX form?

Example: I have a form with an TADOConnection component. I wish that the properties of this component can be modified by the user when he loads my ActiveX control.

[image]

### UPDATE

@TOndrej gives me a very nice sample, but this sample only works for components derived from an ActiveX control. How can I accomplish this same effect with a VCL component like a TImage or TMemo? Is it possible to publish all the properties without rewriting each property to expose them manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ADO components are already ActiveX objects, so the easiest way is to expose the connection as a simple property of your ActiveX form:

In the type library editor, add "Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.1 Library" to the list of used libraries. This will generate `ADODB_TLB.pas` unit in your project directory.

[image]

Then you can declare a new read-only property `Connection` of type `Connection` (this type is declared in `ADODB_TLB` unit) in your `IActiveFormX` interface.

[image]

In the implementation, you can simply return the interface from your `TADOConnection` component:

```
type
  THackADOConnection = class(TADOConnection);

function TActiveFormX.Get_Connection: Connection;
begin
  Result := Connection(THackADOConnection(ADOConnection).ConnectionObject);
end;
```

The `THackADOConnection` typecast is only necessary because `ConnectionObject` is protected. The outer `Connection` typecast is there to get rid of the compiler error "Incompatible types: ADODB_TLB._Connection and ADOInt._Connection."

Comment: thanks very much for you recomendation, this work for components derived from an activex, but how can this with an VCL component like an timage or tmemo?

Comment: You can write another interface exposing the component's methods and properties, declare a property of that type on your active form, and write an implementation delegating the calls to your underlying component.